# comparing 2 char variables

Tags: c

```
int compare (char * s, char * pre) 
{ 
   int x = 0; 
   char p; 
   char orig; 
   while (pre[x] != '\0') 
   { 
      printf("%c", tolower(pre[x]) );
      printf("%c", tolower(s[x]) );
      orig = tolower(s[x]);
      p = tolower(s[x]);
      if (orig != p); 
      { 
         return 0;
      } 
      x++; 
   } 

   return 1;
}
```

expected return : 1    (values identical till end of loop)
resulted return : 0    (values don't match)

Comment: Where is the rest of your code? Most importantly, where are the declarations?

Comment: What are the types of `orig` and `p`?

Comment: We are willing to help if you post a minimally working example.

Comment: `if( orig != p );` remove `;`.

Comment: int compare (char * s, char * pre)
{
    int x = 0;
    char p; char orig;
    while (pre[x] != '\0')
    {
        printf("%c",tolower(pre[x]) );
        printf("%c",tolower(s[x]) );

        orig = tolower(s[x]);
        p = tolower(s[x]);

       if( orig != p );
        {
            return 0;
        }
        x++;
    }
    return 1;
}

Comment: @user3456703: Add that code into your question.

Comment: Voted to close as this is a simple typo... see @BLUEPIXY's comment for detail/answer.

Comment: This code has a bug, even after correcting for the ";".  It should NOT be closed as off-topic.

Comment: The reason for the always-zero-return has been identified as the typo, so the on-hold/close is correct. The always-one would need to be a new question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tautology:

```
orig = tolower(s[x]); p = tolower(s[x]); if( orig != p ) etc.
```

Probably? should be:

```
orig = tolower(s[x]); p = tolower(pre[x]); if( orig != p ) etc.
```

Note the ; was removed from the if stmt.

Comment: @staticx, in the first example, orig and p are from the same entry in the s array, they are always true, the semi-colon essentially "ends" the if statement so that it has no effect, true or false.  In the second example two different arrays, s and pre, are used, and can have different values at the same index into the array.

Comment: Oh I get that.. It was the tautology part.

Comment: @staticx, tautology means "always" true.

Comment: Yep, got that too. I just went back and read it again. I see where the problem lies now. It wasn't readily apparent :)

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities that I can think of:

- Different types (signedness?) for `orig` and `p`. That could cause comparisons and/or assignments to behave "strangely". Without at least the declarations for those variables it would be hard to tell.
- Multiple threads accessing/modifying `s[x]` simultaneously, which could cause `s[x]` to change between your two assignments to `orig` and `p`.

**EDIT**:

As mentioned in one of the comments  to the question, the conditional is a no-op due to a misplaced semicolon (`;`). Try removing that and see if the issue persists.